# IndexError: index 2047 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1638

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I want to train my dataset with training data and validation data.
Total data is *2048*, train data is *1638*, and validation data is *410* (20% of total).

Here are my codes

1. loading data (org: total training data)

   ```
    org_x = train_csv.drop(['id', 'digit', 'letter'], axis=1).values
    org_x = org_x.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)  
    org_x = org_x/255
    org_x = np.array(org_x)
    org_x = org_x.reshape(-1, 1, 28, 28)
    org_x = torch.Tensor(org_x)

    x_test = test_csv.drop(['id','letter'], axis=1).values
    x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)     
    x_test = x_test/255
    x_test = np.array(x_test)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 1, 28, 28)
    x_test = torch.Tensor(x_test)

    y = train_csv['digit']
    y = list(y)
    print(len(y))
    org_y = np.zeros([len(y), 1])
    for i in range(len(y)):
      org_y[i] = y[i]
    org1 = np.array(org_y, dtype=object)
   ```
2. splitting data (org: total training data)

   ```
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

    x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(
       org, org1, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
   ```
3. transform

   ```
    transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToPILImage(),
                            transforms.ToTensor(),
                            transforms.Normalize((0.5, ), (0.5, )) ])
   ```
4. dataset

   ```
    class kmnistDataset(data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, images, labels=None, transforms=None):
        self.x = images
        self.y = labels
        self.transforms = transforms

    def __len__(self):
        return (len(self.x))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        data = np.asarray(self.x[idx][0:]).astype(np.uint8)

        if self.transforms:
            data = self.transforms(data)

        if self.y is not None:
            return (data, self.y[i])
        else:
            return data

    train_data = kmnistDataset(x_train, y_train, transform)
    valid_data = kmnistDataset(x_valid, y_valid, transform)

    train_loader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)
    valid_loader = DataLoader(valid_data, batch_size=16, shuffle = False)
   ```

I'll skip the model structure.

5. training(Here, I got the error message)

   ```
   n_epochs = 30

   valid_loss_min = np.Inf

   for epoch in range(1, n_epochs+1):
       train_loss = 0
       valid_loss = 0

   ###################
   # train the model #
   ###################
   model.train()   
   for data in train_loader:
       inputs, labels = data[0], data[1]
       optimizer.zero_grad()
       output = model(inputs)
       loss = criterion(output, labels)
       loss.backward()
       optimizer.step()
       train_loss += loss.item()*data.size(0)

   #####################
   # validate the model#
   #####################
   model.eval()
   for data in valid_loader:
       inputs, labels = data[0], data[1]
       output = model(inputs)
       loss = criterion(output, labels)
       valid_loss += loss.item()*data.size(0)


   train_loss = train_loss/ len(train_loader.dataset)
   valid_loss = valid_loss / len(valid_loader.dataset)

   print('Epoch: {} \tTraining Loss: {:.6f} \tValidation Loss: {:.6f}'.format(
       epoch, train_loss, valid_loss))
   ```

Although I checked the data size, I got the error message below.

> index 2047 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1638

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-b8783819421f> in <module>
     11     ###################
     12     model.train()
---> 13     for data in train_loader:
     14         inputs, labels = data[0], data[1]
     15         optimizer.zero_grad()

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    433         if self._sampler_iter is None:
    434             self._reset()
--> 435         data = self._next_data()
    436         self._num_yielded += 1
    437         if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in_next_data(self)
    473     def _next_data(self):
    474         index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 475         data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    476         if self._pin_memory:
    477             data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in fetch(self, 
possibly_batched_index)
     42     def fetch(self, possibly_batched_index):
     43         if self.auto_collation:
---> 44             data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
     45         else:
     46             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in <listcomp(.0)
     42     def fetch(self, possibly_batched_index):
     43         if self.auto_collation:
---> 44             data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
     45         else:
     46             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

<ipython-input-38-e5c87dd8a7ff> in __getitem__(self, idx)
     17 
     18         if self.y is not None:
---> 19             return (data, self.y[i])
     20         else:
     21             return data

IndexError: index 2047 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1638
```

Can you explain why and how to solve it?

Comment: Could you print out the shapes of `x_train` and `y_train` just before calling `kmnistDataset``?

Comment: torch.Size([1638, 1, 28, 28])   # print(x_train.shape) //
torch.Size([410, 1, 28, 28])    # print(x_valid.shape) //
torch.Size([1638, 1])     # print(y_train.shape) //
torch.Size([410, 1]).      # print(y_valid.shape)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, you are using incorrect shapes: `org_x = org_x.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)`. The channel axis you be the second one (unlike in *TensorFlow*), as `(batch_size, channels, height, width)`:

```
org_x = org_x.reshape(-1, 1, 28, 28)
```

Same with `x_test`

```
x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 1, 28, 28)
```

---

Also, you are accessing a list out of bound. You accessed `self.y` with `i`. Seems to me you should be returning `(data, self.y[idx])` instead.

Comment: Thanks, completely didn't know it. But the same issue still occurs. :(

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. I have another issue. Can I ask more after my struggling?

Comment: If it's not too far off from this post, you can ask here. Otherwise you should create another post, I should be there to respond ;)